# Limiting floats to a varying number (decided by the end-user) of decimal points in Python

Tags: python-3.x, precision

So, I've learned quite a few ways to control the precision when I'm dealing with floats.

Here is an example of 3 different techniques:

```
somefloat=0.0123456789

print("{0:.10f}".format(somefloat))
print("%.5f" % somefloat)
print(Decimal(somefloat).quantize(Decimal(".01")))
```

This will print:

0.0123456789

0.01235

0.01

In all of the above examples, the precision itself is a fixed value, but how could I turn the precision itself a variable that could be
be entered by the end-user?

I mean, the fixed precision values are now inside quatations marks, and I can't seem to find a way to add any variable there. Is there a way, anyway?

I'm on Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using format:

```
somefloat=0.0123456789
precision = 5
print("{0:.{1}f}".format(somefloat, precision))
# 0.01235
```

Using old-style string interpolation:

```
print("%.*f" % (precision, somefloat))
# 0.01235
```

Using decimal:

```
import decimal
D = decimal.Decimal
q = D(10) ** -precision
print(D(somefloat).quantize(q))
# 0.01235
```

Comment: Impressive, all of the above are working perfectly with your solution. You came up with an elegant solution for the third one (the decimal thing), that was the most problematic for me. I can't thank you enough for this help.